# Animate a zig-zag line between 2 points

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a page where different elements animate into view when you scroll down the page. You can see an example here:

https://codepen.io/moy/pen/vpEQxw

I have an image on one side and some text on the other. This all works quite well so far. You'll notice I have a dot on each image, the position of which will change on each 'item' and I need a line to appear from that dot and link it to the text. You can see a crude red example on the CodePen.

I thought about just fading the image/div in but I don't think that'd look very good. So animating the line from one side to the other would be best but I'm not sure that's possible due to the turns? It's also going to be a pain to make sure the dot, line and text block line up. Good news is the lines will be hidden on mobile/tablet so absolute positioning and fixed heights/widths are ok.

If I could animate the width of the container from 0px wide that could give it the effect of the line 'growing' but it could skew the image a bit. It also might look odd at the end when the line runs vertical? Example CSS below...

```
.lines {
    height: 126px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    transition: all .5s 1s;
    width: 0;

    .in-view & {
        width: 311px;
    }
}

.lines__inner {
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kXzOvR/test_line.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    height: 126px;
    width: 311px;
}
```

Each of the 4 line graphics will be different but I could use an ID for each one to specify the correct images + dimensions. While they are different, they'll all be made up of the same shapes, just different length lines. So, for example, each graphic will have a line coming from the dot, moving across and up, before breaking into 2 forks.

Anyone have any good solutions for this?

Comment: I would try to achieve the effect with mask(s) that slide to reveal the line-work graphic. It's a steam-age animation technique but simple to code. No great penalty in trying it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky one. I was thinking if I use an SVG I wonder if there's a way to stretch the image but maybe the stroke remains the same.

Comment: SVG should certainly be simple to stretch/position using the [SVG transform interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform). Maybe you should try that first.